# Google Playにアプリを提出するためのバージョンコード設定方法について

Tags: android, cordova

cordova5.2.0を利用してARM版でアプリをビルドしました。

このとき生成されるアプリのバージョンコードが、以前作成したバージョンコードより大きな値とならないため、Google Playに提出できません。

どのように解決すればよいでしょうか？

Comment: cordovaを知りませんが、バージョンの番号をセットすればいいだけでは？

Comment: タグに`monaca`が入っていますが、`cordova`で解答を求めているのですか？`monaca`で解答を求めているのですか？既に`cordova`からの回答が付いていますが、`monaca`の場合、`monaca`の設定も変更しないと上書きされる可能性があります。

Answer (score 1):

config.xmlのwidgetタグに下のように、「android-versionCode」を指定することで変更できると思います。

```
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova"
  version="0.0.1"
  android-versionCode="7"
  ios-CFBundleVersion="3.3.3">
```

■Cordova ドキュメントリンク
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref/#link-2

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事に、グーグルとアマゾンに登録できました。